# DLNA/UPNP Technology with iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, upnp, dlna

I am new to DLNA And UPNP Technology. I am building one app to cast videos(specially Live Streaming formats: .M3U8 & .RTMP) and audios to smartTVs(Samsung, LG, Sony, Panasonic, Toshiba, Sharp and Philips). I searched a lot about DLNA/UPNP and also found some helpful resources but confused at some points.

> 1. Can we cast Live Streaming Videos?
> 2. How to test app with all
>      brand smart TVs as I don't have any smart TV. 3).
> 3. Which library is
>      better to use in swift?

And also suggest me Good tutorials and steps to use technology into App I would like to use swift language but suggestions for Objective-C also ok :) any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, you can cast live streaming videos. I suggest you start off with something simple like chromecast. https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-videos-ios

2) You will need to buy the TVs to test, some of the manufacturers provide the emulators to test apps on their tvs, but I doubt you'd be able to cast live videos to them.

3) You will need to use to the libraries provided by each manufacturer, not all of them would be written for swift natively, but I imagine it wouldn't be hard to get them working with swift. [Samsung's SmartView SDK is written to be compatible with both swift and Obj-C](http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/)